# Whats the difference between + and , in console.log()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
console.log('The initial state: ', store.getState());
```

This line gives the correct output.

```
console.log('The initial state: '+ store.getState());
```

This line gives a strange output: The initial state Object Object.
Whats the difference?

Also why does it give 2 objects as output instead of just 1?

Comment: The first is passing two parameters to `console.log`, the second is attempting to concatenate the two values into a single string and pass only one parameter. Attempting to coerce an object to a string results in `Object Object`.

Answer (score 1):

By using a , you are telling console.log that it should take multiple arguments.

The +, on the other hand, is telling JavaScript that it needs to *combine both arguments into one single argument*. Since the string can't fit together with an object, you get what you are seeing. Console.log does a much better job of displaying the object as an object instead of trying to convert it to a string.